# How to detect if the computer is locked in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, linux, windows

I am looking to build a remote monitoring system for my computers, one of which is Linux-based and one which is Windows. I'd like to use Node.js to build this system.

I've already found one library that allows me to lock my device. However, it doesn't provide me with an unlock event or boolean. This means I am unable to reliably update my monitoring system when my computer is unlocked (without requiring user input).

Is there some sort of way to get this state programmatically, or a Node library which handles it? I've seen a few libraries to lock the screen or enter the screensaver, but none that have a callback for afterwards.

Comment: Wrap it in a function, call the function set the global variable to a boolean value. Than have a check function to determine the locked state, if its locked run the unlock function, if its unlocked run the lock function.

Comment: @Raymond I think you missed the entire point of the question. _"Than have a check function to determine the locked state"_ How? That's the question.

Comment: OP, have you tried `https://www.npmjs.com/package/lock-your-windows`? It's only for Windows but perhaps it could still be helpful to you.